# How to refresh visible cells in GridViewColumn?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik

I've added custom GridViewColumn with custom property. I need to refresh visible cells in this column by changing of this property. I've added subscription on PropertyChanged, but I don't know what to do next. How to refresh cells in current column?

Comment: i think you are not using the binding with notification in you grid.

Comment: It doesn't related to Items. This code is related to CustomColumn. This CustomColumn should refresh cells itself, because it settings doesn't related to ViewModel. It's View problem only.